# Sharepoint Online Addin - Add item to list - CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom

I have created a SharePoint Addin following this step by step Microsoft [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins) and it works fine.

Now I would like to add some javascript CSOM to my "internal" list and I wrote the following code:

```
function createListItem() {
    var siteUrl = 'https://mysharepointaddress.sharepoint.com/sites/app';
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('New Employees in Seattle');

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My New Item!');

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

The list name cannot be found.
I would try with `.getById(guid)` but i don't know how to find the guid of this list.

Tested on a normal list, created via Site Content - Add an app, and the code works fine.

Any advice is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add item to app list, please replace the code below

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
```

with

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

Example: https://github.com/OfficeDev/SharePoint-Add-in-JSOM-BasicDataOperations

Answer (score 0):

To get the list Id :

1. Go to your target list in Sharepoint
2. From the ribbon select **List** the click on **List settings**.
3. You will find it in the URL :
   List=%7B**92BFE60B-147A-49CD-8C86-38CD90987235**%7D
4. Take the Id between **%7B** and **%7D**, so the Guid is **92BFE60B-147A-49CD-8C86-38CD90987235**

Just to be sure that you get the good Title of your list, try to get it from URL of your list.