# SharePoint Add-In, can't find “Style Library”? Language Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin

I have an Add-In that works fine to install in an English setup of SharePoint. However, when I test this in another language I run into an issue.

The issue is with this code:

```
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Style Library");
```

I get the error that the list "Style Library" can't be found on the site `https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/Testsite`.

In addition to this I also need the following to be language independent:

```
list.get_fields().getByTitle("Title");
```

How can I do this in another way without being language dependent?
I've tried to search everywhere but can't find a way.
Is this something to do with "Metadata Language"? Can that be changed for an Add-In?

Comment: Which language you are using for your SharePoint site?

Comment: On this specific site I'm using Swedish, but as this is an AddIn to be installed on several different sites I need this to work independently of the language.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the SharePoint List/Library using **GUID** instead of its Title.

To get the list instance using GUID try below code:

```
var listGUID = "92BFE60B-147A-49CD-8C86-38CD90987235"; // This GUID is just for example
var list = web.get_lists().getById(listGUID);
```

[SP.ListCollection.getById Method (sp.js)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj247185(v%3Doffice.15)).

You can find the GUID of your SharePoint List/Library by following the steps from any of the below links:

1. [Finding the Id (Guid) for a SharePoint List](https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2008/04/29/finding-the-id-guid-for-a-sharepoint-list/).
2. [Sharepoint Online Addin - Add item to list - CSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231544/sharepoint-online-addin-add-item-to-list-csom)

**Note**: The GUID for the Style Library will be different for all SharePoint sites (If you are planning to use this Add-in across multiple sites).

Comment: Thanks, is this an ID that is always the same for all Sharepoint sites, or something unique per site?

Comment: No, this will not be the same for all SharePoint sites.

Comment: Maybe you can try using `GetList` method as mentioned [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/250780/csom-get-list-instance-from-url-is-not-working) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8fe1aa38-3b23-4d5b-b9b1-ecfc81b7ada0/how-to-get-the-splist-or-document-library-using-the-internal-name-and-not-with-the-title) **OR** the workaround mentioned [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116807/how-to-get-list-by-url-using-sharepoint-2013-csom) to get the list using its URL. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: There is not a way to get the list or field based on their "real" English name? So for instance "Site Library" or "Title", instead of their translated name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getById(id)` method.

```
var list = web.get_lists().getById(listId);
```

- [ListCollection.GetById method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listcollection.getbyid(v=office.15).aspx) - returns the list with the
  specified list identifier
- [ListCollection.GetByTitle method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listcollection.getbytitle(v=office.15).aspx) - returns the list with the
  specified title from the collection